# VB silverlight for windows phone "LateBinding"

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hello i am developing an application in vb for windows phone and i need to do this :

`Private Sub ItemTap(sender As Object, e As GestureEventArgs)
        Dim url = "/" & sender.Content & ".xaml"
        Me.NavigationService.Navigate(url)
End Sub`

i am having in my page a listbox , the content of the listbox is an item with two atributes :
name and tag

i want to use this sub in order to navigate to this paga : /name.xaml
but it has an error that says that url should not be a string and anotherone that says that the targeted platform does not support latebinding :S
any ideas ??
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare url... As an Uri:

```
Dim url as New Uri("/" & sender.Content & ".xaml", UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: it keeps telling me that the targeted platform does not suport LateBinding :S

Comment: That's because you need to cast `sender` before accessing the `Content` property.